# getPixel() doesn't return coordinates

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that returns coordinates of color match:

```
color = (54,175,49)
image = 'green.png'
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image)
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image, region=location) != None:
        s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=location)
        for x in range(s.width):
                for y in range(s.height):
                    print("searching...")
                    if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:
                        print("found")
                        cord = x
                        cord2 = y
                        break
```

but it stops on `print("searching")`. Any ideas?

Comment: you can debug that easily, print the value of `s.getpixel((x, y))`

Comment: `break` only ends the innermost loop.  That still leaves the outer `for x` and `while True:` loops running.  If this code is in a function, `return` might be more appropriate than `break`.

Comment: It won't work because it stops on `print("searching")` .  My mistake in post. Changing from break to return also did not work.

Comment: Does it show any errors? If not, try put a `try except` outside `if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:` to see if there is any errors. Or place a print statement below the if statement. But maybe it doesnt find the color so it only prints `searching`

Comment: No, it just loops the `print("searching...")` and doesn't get past `if s.getpixel((x, y)) == color:`. And it should find the color because i tried putting that line of code alone and it worked just fine.

Comment: You can use `raise Exception` in place of `break` to stop the process when the first pixel with `color = (54,175,49)` is found. Before the `raise Exception`, you can `print(f"x: {x}")`, `print(f"y: {y}")`, `print(f"color: {s.getpixel((x, y))}")` to double-check.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Question: how can i write or save the `x,y` coordinates from `s.getpixel((x,y))` into a variable?